# Split JSON value to obtain new JSON with news properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split

This is my first post today because I'm exhausted.

I try since few days to make something that looks simple but not for me...

I've this JSON :

```
[
   {
      "GpName":"AAAAAA",
      "Contacts":"US;Toto;\nESI;James;james@mail.com "
   },
   {
      "GpName":"BBBBBB",
      "Contacts":"ESI;Sebastien;sebastien@mail.com\nUS;Ahmid;\nESI;Stephane ;Stephane@mail.com"
   },
   {
      "GpName":"CCCCCC", 
 "Contacts":"ESI;Marc;Marc@mail.com\nUS;Olivier;olivier@mail.com\nUS;Jean;jean@mail.com"
   }
]
```

I try to use the split array function, I don't have the result expected.
How could I obtain :

```
[
   {
      "GpName":"AAAAAA",
      "Contacts":["Zone":"US",
                  "User":"Toto"
                  "Mail": " "],
                 ["Zone":"ESI",
                  "User":"James",
                  "Mail":"james@gmail.com "]
   },
   {
      "GpName":"BBBBBB",
      "Contacts":["Zone":"ESI",
                  "User":"Sebastien"
                  "Mail": "sebastien@mail.com"],
                 ["Zone":"US",
                  "User":"Ahmid ",
                  "Mail":" "]
                 ["Zone":"ESI",
                  "User":"Stephane",
                  "Mail":"Stephane@mail.com"]
   },
   {
      "GpName":"CCCCCC",
      "Contacts":["Zone":"ESI",
                  "User":"Marc"
                  "Mail": "Marc@mail.com"],
                 ["Zone":"US",
                  "User":"Olivier",
                  "Mail":" "]
                 ["Zone":"US",
                  "User":"Jean",
                  "Mail":"Jean@mail.com"]
   }
]
```

As you can see, sometimes I've email, sometime not.

Any help would be very grateful

Comment: Don't manipulate JSON, parse it to an Object first ... `the split array function` - can you show what you've tried ... there is no split array function

Comment: Please provide the code of your `split` functionality.

Comment: Maybe you almost finish it, please share your split function and we can help to see what you missed.

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.split` Split a string into substrings and `Array.map` to generate an array.

```js
let input = [{ "GpName": "AAAAAA", "Contacts": "US;Toto;\nESI;James;james@mail.com " }, { "GpName": "BBBBBB", "Contacts": "ESI;Sebastien;sebastien@mail.com\nUS;Ahmid;\nESI;Stephane ;Stephane@mail.com" }, { "GpName": "CCCCCC", "Contacts": "ESI; Marc; Marc@mail.com\nUS; Olivier; olivier@mail.com\nUS; Jean; jean@mail.com" }]

let result = input.map(({ GpName, Contacts }) => ({
    GpName,
    Contacts: Contacts.split("\n").map(line => {
        let [Zone, User, Mail] = line.split(";");
        return { Zone, User, Mail }
    })
}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Tks a lot for your answer it seems to be solution but as I said, I'm using javascript language ECMASCRIPT 5/ES5 and I don't have "let","map" and others...

Comment: [compile it into ES5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&filetype=js#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgDgV0gXggbQN4QEQHE4ByAhgLYjYBcOAgrXdgDQ4DCA9jGEQMZgDOlOAKoBlANwAVVmFaiAOjACiwgJKiAUqRC9RAK028AAiSJRgAOi6sSOCAF8mWPIU0DsAIQ+fGLdpx78qbCVVYRAAIyJeMCgQGFFecMjo2KMTc0sSeRFRagALEigAEzlFFVFhMBA4XKIYEAhyyurakFTTCytsOwccfGIyV2Yh4e9sNg5uPldg0QgAWSIAJy5ZheW29KsssQgAeWAoADcYxdnWA+OQRY2OzJhsiDUQWtmdZ5gbjK7bAF0AKFAkEWWgQwBQ0HgSDMxjgAApYVg+pomOM-Hw7ABKCDIAB8EARfwgRIgSLIDEJxNRk14VCp-jMvDgBzAsOw8mwGOhRDhBzq2LxGApxOJgPQAC12CAmIIEosmAtTD9sRBeSAGUyoCzsKIOULhRBgWAEIsYBAsBK6tLZfK0nY9bYMX8HRjRH9LDBeOc1cBWABzWHA3igsAYoA)

Comment: Tks for this update, I was in vacation and can't test before today. When I run this, the map function is used, but as I said, map is not working in my environment (vRO, from vmware). I have to replace the map by another thing

Comment: This is what `map` function do: `function map(array,fn) { let result = []; for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) result.push(fn(array[i],i,array)); return result;}`

Comment: Here is a [map polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#polyfill)

Comment: Hello @Nur , I'm go to try with this and keep you update.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried on my side

```
var EsiEmailList = [];
var EsiEmailListJSON = [];
var myJSON = JSON.parse(BgManagerInfoList);

for (key in myJSON) {
    gpInfo = myJSON[key];
    var gpName= gpInfo.GpName;
    var gpContact = gpInfo.Contacts;
    EsiEmailListJSON.push(gpContact);
}

EsiEmailList=JSON.stringify(EsiEmailListJSON);

EsiEmailListSplit = EsiEmailListJSON/split("\n");
for (data in EsiEmailListSplit){
    contactInfo = EsiEmailListJSON[data];
    System.log ("contactInfo: " + contactInfo);
}
```

The result is something like this :

```
**ContactInfo**: US;Toto;
ESI;James;james@mail.com

**ContactInfo**: ESI;Sebastien;sebastien@mail.com
US;Ahmid;
ESI;Stephane;Stephane@mail.com

**ContactInfo**:ESI;Marc;Marc@mail.com
US;Olivier;olivier@mail.com
US;Jean;jean@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue :
Error in (Workflow:TEst / map function (item1)#37) TypeError: Cannot find function map in object
I tested the polyfill but it's not working
Here the code

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
Array.prototype.map = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {
var T, A, k;
if (this == null) {
  throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
}
var O = Object(this);
var len = O.length >>> 0;
if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
  throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
}
if (arguments.length > 1) {
  T = arguments[1];
}
A = new Array(len);
k = 0;
while (k < len) {
  var kValue, mappedValue;
  if (k in O) {
    kValue = O[k];
    mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
    A[k] = mappedValue;
  }
  k++;
}
return A;
};
}
var input = [{ "GpName": "AAAAAA", "Contacts": 
"US;Toto;\nESI;James;james@mail.com " }, { "GpName": "BBBBBB", "Contacts": 
"ESI;Sebastien;sebastien@mail.com\nUS;Ahmid;\nESI;Stephane ;Stephane@mail.com" 
}, { "GpName": "CCCCCC", "Contacts": "ESI; Marc; Marc@mail.com\nUS; Olivier; 
olivier@mail.com\nUS; Jean; jean@mail.com" }];
var result = input.map(function (_a) {
var GpName = _a.GpName, Contacts = _a.Contacts;
return ({
    GpName: GpName,
    Contacts: Contacts.split("\n").map(function (line) {
        var _a = line.split(";"), Zone = _a[0], User = _a[1], Mail = _a[2];
        return { Zone: Zone, User: User, Mail: Mail };
    })
});
});
```

Can I Maybe use the for each instead of map, something like this :

```
var inputJSON = JSON.parse(BgManagerInfoList);
for each(a in inputJSON ){
var GpName = a.GpName;
var Contacts = a.Contacts;
//System.log ("GpName: " + GpName);
//System.log ("Contacts: " + Contacts);
for each(b in Contacts){
    b = line.split(";");
    var Zone = b[0];
    var User = b[1];
    var Mail = b[2];
System.log ("Zone:" + Zone + ", User: " + User + ", Mail: " + Mail );
}
}
```

I've a value for GpName and Contacts but the for each is not working for Contacts

Comment: It should work, 1st of all, ES5 support `Array.prototype.map` I think some lib or runtime might tamper with build in prototype... Remove `if` block `if (!Array.prototype.map) { ... }`.  So, it will forcedly override default map functionality, OR you can try `map` function, I already share that, code: `function map(array,fn) { let result = []; for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) result.push(fn(array[i],i,array)); return result;}`

Comment: Does other build in array function working? like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem :

```
var input = JSON.parse(BgManagerInfoList);
for each(a in input){
var GpName = a.GpName ;
var Contacts = a.Contacts;
//System.log ("GpName: " + GpName);
contactSplit = Contacts.split('\n');
System.log ("Contacts: " + Contacts);
for each (a in  contactSplit){   
var ContactOnly = a.split(";");
//System.log ("ContactsSplit: " + ContactsSplit);
var Zone = ContactOnly[0];
var User = ContactOnly[1]; 
var Mail = ContactOnly[2];
System.log ("Zone:" + Zone + ", User: " + User + ", Mail: " + Mail );
}
}
```

I made a first split of each lines, and for each line I made another split on the ";".

I got the expected result. Tks a lot for your suggestion, they helped me to understand of map is working and adapt my code to get the result.

I've to push the result in a table and work with.